# Failed: fakeGenericModalComponent.modalData is undefined in defaullt jasmine test case

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am working on getting the default test cases for an application my team is developing to work. At this point with particular component I am working is to get the component to create successfully.

The code in the component.ts file is this

```
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { FlexTableComponent } from '../flex-table/flex-table.component';
import { TableData } from 'src/app/models/pcplan-app.models';
import { CompileNgModuleMetadata } from '@angular/compiler';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-generic-modal',
 templateUrl: './generic-modal.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./generic-modal.component.scss']
})

export class GenericModalComponent implements OnInit {
 modalData: TableData;
 selectedRow: number;
 noData = false;

 constructor(
   public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<GenericModalComponent>,
   @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
     this.modalData = data;}
     
   onCancelClick(): void {
     this.dialogRef.close();
   }

   onSelect(row) {
     this.selectedRow = row;
    }

   onOkClick(): void {
     this.dialogRef.close(this.selectedRow);
   }

   ngOnInit(){
     if(this.modalData.data.length === 0){
       this.noData = true; 
     }
   }
 }
```

The class for the component I am having issues with in the test case is

```
export class TableData {
  data: Array<any>;
  displayObject: any;
  colWidths: any;
  title: string;
}
```

the spec.ts file currently has this code in it (I have tried several way to mock the modaldata)

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { GenericModalComponent } from './generic-modal.component';
import { MatDialogRef, MatDialog, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TableData } from 'src/app/models/pcplan-app.models';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-generic-modal',
  template: '<div></div>'
})
class fakeGenericModalComponent{
    static modalData: TableData;
};

describe('GenericModalComponent', () => {
  let component: GenericModalComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<GenericModalComponent>;
  let mockMatDialogRef;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    fakeGenericModalComponent.modalData.data =  [];

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ GenericModalComponent ],
      providers: [
        {provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: mockMatDialogRef},
        {provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: fakeGenericModalComponent}
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(GenericModalComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

This is the error message I am getting on this test, I am sure it will wind up being something dumb, but why is modalData undefined in the results when it looks to me like it is defined.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `const`

```
const fakeGenericModalComponent = {
   modalData: {
      data : []
   }
}
```

rather than `class` and then use `useValue`

Comment: Shashank Vivek, I tried doing that and now what I am getting is:

TypeError: this.modalData.data is undefined in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js (line 1045)